# Picking a check digit algorithm

Tags: hash, one-time-password, checksum

I am generating random OTP-style strings that serve as a short-term identifier to link two otherwise unrelated systems (which have authentication at each end). These need to be read and re-entered by users, so in order to reduce the error rate and reduce the opportunities for forgery, I'd like to make one of the digits a check digit. At present my random string conforms to the pattern (removing `I` and `O` to avoid confusion):

```
^[ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ][0-9]{4}$
```

I want to append one extra decimal digit for the check. So far I've implemented this as a BLAKE2 hash (from libsodium) that's converted to decimal and truncated to 1 char. This gives only 10 possibilities for the check digit, which isn't much. My primary objective is to detect single character errors in the input.

This approach kind of works, but it seems that one digit is not enough to detect single char errors, and undetected errors are quite easy to find, for example `K37705` and `K36705` are both considered valid.

I do not have a time value baked into this OTP; instead it's purely random and I'm relying on keeping a record of the OTPs that have been generated recently for each user, which are deleted periodically, and I'm reducing opportunities for brute-forcing by rate and attempt-count limiting.

I'm guessing that BLAKE2 isn't a good choice here, but given there are only 10 possibilities for the result, I don't know that others will be better. What would be a better algorithm/approach to use?

Comment: I don't think this is a question of algorithm. It simply is not possible that you can encode the amount of information needed to detect an arbitrary change of any of these characters into a single digit. There is likely some math to proof this. If it would not be about arbitrary changes but about likely changes (i.e. P vs. R, E vs. F but not A vs. Z) it might be different.

Comment: A check digit of the same order as the others would likely work better. One suggestion would be the Damm algorithm with a quasigroup matching the order of your symbols. It is made to catch errors commonly made in this situation like transposition of two adjacent symbols or incorrect symbol.

Comment: While not exactly the same as what you are trying to do, Bitcoin uses something called a Base58Chcek to detect typos in bitcoin addresses and to avoid similar characters.  It works by basically appending the last 4 bytes of the double-sha256 of the payload to the payload, then taking base58-encodeing the result (to eliminate similar-looking characters).  See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32353/how-do-i-check-the-checksum-of-a-bitcoin-address for more info.

Comment: I am voting to migrate to StackOverflow since detecting typos is not a security problem. If this is intended to be a security mechanism, then you'll need to somehow add a key that the attacker does not know; like the checksum needs to be a (truncated) public key signature or keyed MAC.

Comment: A [Luhn code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) is a common but imperfect way to check for human transcription errors. There are other approaches that are more optimal in an information-theoretical sense, and there are also optimal error correcting codes. Cryptographic hash functions are not suitable here. However, your use case does not benefit from error detection. Either the OTP code is in the database, or it isn't. You can select code length, validity period, and number of tries to keep the probability of guesses low enough.

Comment: Thanks @amon, a Luhn code looks like it will do nicely. It gives a small, incremental advantage – the number is indistinguishable from a random one, but is partly verifiable without a database/API lookup. If I was asking *how to write* a check algorithm, this would have been better asked on SO, but I'm not asking that. I think algorithm selection would be off-topic there, and far more appropriate here, and Steffen Ullrich's comment mostly confirms what I suspected, that there's not enough data in 1 digit to do much that's useful.

Answer (score 0):

### Frame challenge

Why do you need a check digit?

It doesn't improve security, and a five digits is *trivial* for most humans to get correct. Check if server side and return an error message if it's wrong.

Normal TOTP tokens are commonly 6 digits, and actors such as google has determined that people in general manage to get them orrect.

Comment: I’m not looking for more security, just more reliability. As far as the user knows, it’s just another digit. I figured that it would be more useful to spot transcription problems as early as possible, possibly even prior to an API lookup, “for free”